# Youtube Video Wont Embed

Tags: html, iframe

(First question here, sorry)

So my husband needed my help for a school assignment where he needs a small website. Everything went fine until I had to embed a short youtube video onto the page...

Using the code provided (as suggested by several websites) just gets me a big blank space on my page and I'm confused as to why.

Website here:
https://eznoserronas.000webhostapp.com/index.html#

On that page I used an old  tag because that got some videos to show up, but not the one I needed. I have the iframe in my working copy, and I just can't seem to find any reason it's not working. Nothing in the CSS would affect this.

Comment: Did you copy the embed link in the youtube video?

Comment: Edit your question and post all of the code here. I went to the link and it set off my antivirus as DANGEROUS WEBSITE BLOCKED

Comment: On Youtube hit share and then embed and copy the embed code.

Comment: @carljan Yes, I used the exact embed link that I got ( <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ywUWQy53Cg0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> )

Comment: @mlegg http://pastebin.com/FFB9W2dL Full code for the page

Comment: Fix your code errors. https://validator.w3.org/nu/#l51c103

Comment: @mlegg Aha, there we go. That got it fixed, thank you =)